# Flex DataBinding in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have datagrid Columns FirstName, LastName and FullName.

I need to bind FirstName and LastName column fields to give FullName ?? data provider gives only  FirstName and LastName

Help me in this!

Answer (score 2):

Use a labelFunction in your FullName column :

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="FullName" labelFunction="getFullName"/>  

private function getFullName(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String 
{  
    return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName;
}
```